# parsing timestamp using simpledateformat

Tags: java, date, timestamp, compare, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse date(which can be in any of the formats) using `SimpleDateFormat`. For that I have prepared a list of formats using symbols available in `SimpleDateFormat` and tried parsing the date string using the following code-:

```
private Pair<Date,SimpleDateFormat> parseTimeStamp(String input)
    {
        Pair<Date,SimpleDateFormat> dateTime=null;
        for (SimpleDateFormat dateFormat : TIMESTAMP_FORMATS) {
            try {
                Date temp = dateFormat.parse(input);
                dateTime=new Pair<Date, SimpleDateFormat>(temp,dateFormat);
                break;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
    return dateTime;
    }

private static final List<SimpleDateFormat> TIMESTAMP_FORMATS = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>() {{
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhh:mm:ssa"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhh:mma"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhha"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH:mm"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssa"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmma"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddZ"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddz"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddX"));

    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyhh:mm:ssa"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyhh:mma"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyhha"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyHH"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyhhmmssa"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyhhmma"));
    add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyHHmmss"));
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
   }
}
```

When I parse 06-06-2020 1:08:00PM, returned format is `yyyyMMddHH` instead of `dd-MM-yyyyy hhmmssa`.
I want to ask why is this discrepancy and how to resolve this?

Comment: Your first big mistake is that should not be using `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat`.  They are deprecated.  You should be using `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.  Until you transition to those classes anything you  learn regarding this particular post will be of questionable use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setLenient(false) for your SimpleDateFormats.

```
    private static final List<SimpleDateFormat> TIMESTAMP_FORMATS = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        {
            add(createDf("yyyyMMddhh:mm:ssa"));
            // ....
        }
    };

    private static SimpleDateFormat createDf(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(s);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        return sdf;
    }
```

Comment: Even after using linked list 06-06-2020 1:08:00PM  is parsed as yyyy-MM-ddHHmm whereas expected result is dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ssa